# Converting strings to ints in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

How to covert a DataFrame column containing strings and "-" values to floats. 
I have tried with  `pd.to_numeric` and `pd.Series.astype(int)` but i haven´t success.
What do you recommend??

[image: **DataFrame **]

[image]

Comment: you data is like ip number how you convert them into floats?

Comment: I have tried that. i tried to convert into float64, but i couldn´t

Comment: What is the underlying file type . xls. csv? What tool is displaying the data in the screenshot? Can you post a few lines directly from the file?

Comment: @qeriva is not possible to convert to float numbers like: 196.12.121.1

Comment: ok, i´ll send it . the file was a pdf converted into a .xlsx, just give me a second. In the description of my issue, i have posted a screenshot of my code.

Comment: My guess is  `.` is the thousands separator. Try`thousandsstr='.'` in the `read_csv` . But the `()` which possibly indicate negative may not transform. If still a problem readthe csv lines as text and do something like `line.replace("-","0").replace("(","-").replace(")","").replace(".","")` where `line` is each line read from file.

Comment: ok, i will try, and yes the  `()` sign indicate negative numbers.

Comment: i could replace just `-` sign

Comment: @AndrewLavers do you recommend to do the `replace`separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you want pandas to convert the string `7.629.352` to the float value `7629352.0` and the string `(21.808.956)` to the value `-21808956.0`.

For the first part, it is directly possible with the `thousands` parameter, and it is even possible to process `-` as a NaN:

```
m = read_csv(..., thousands='.', na_values='-')
```

The real problem is the parens for negative values.

You could use a python function to convert the values. A possible alternative would be to post process the dataframe column wise:

```
m = read_csv(..., thousands='.', na_values='-')
for col in m.columns:
    if m[col].dtype == np.dtype('object'):
        m[col] = m[col].str.replace(r'\.', '').str.replace(r'\((.*)\)', r'-\1').astype('float64')
```